# Stiefel–Whitney class and Pontryagin class requirement on a simplicial complex: triangulation and branching structure

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

Given a **simplicial complex with only triangulation and branching structure**, is it enough to define [Stiefel–Whitney class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class) and [Pontryagin class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_class)?

If so, could you explain how to obtain these characteristic classes via a simplicial complex with only triangulation and branching structure?

- A triangulation is given by the simplicial complex.
- A branching structure is a choice of the orientation of each link in the simplicial complex, so that there is no oriented loop on any 2-simplex.

p.s. [According to Tom Goodwillie](https://mathoverflow.net/q/410329/27004): "$_()$ does not require a triangulation (a  structure). The tangent microbundle of a topological manifold has Stiefel-Whitney classes. In fact, even a (stable) spherical fibration on a space X has SW classes; $_$ can be defined as the class that corresponds via the Thom isomorphism to $^$ of the Thom class." If this is true, what do Stiefel–Whitney class and Pontryagin class require in order to be defined on a simplicial complex?

Comment: [cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410418/define-a-characteristic-class-on-a-simplicial-complex-non-manifold)

Comment: As a general rule, you should not post the same questions simultaneously here and on Mathoverflow, in order to avoid duplication of efforts. As a rule of thumb, after posting a question on one cite, after a week, if you did not get an answer, you can post the same question on the other, but leave a note about cross-posting. As noted by Belegradek on MO, your question is unclear since you did not specify which bundle you wish to use in lieu of the tangent bundle. I suggest you think through the case when your complex is a graph, say, a tree. What would be an analogue of the tangent bundle?